# CustomMessageBox (WPtoolkit8): how to use with a ListPicker in PickerMode.Expanded

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, wptoolkit

I tried to use the `WPtoolkit CustomMessageBox` with a `listpicker`.

The same problems can be seen running the CustomMessageBoxSample (in the WPtoolkit solution) only after changing the ItemsSource = new string[] { "5 minutes", "10 minutes", "1 hour", "4 hours", "1 day", "2 days", "10 day" } , that is having more than 5 elements, so it will open in FullMode by default.

In this case, leaving the other code example as it is, clicking the listpicker opens the fullMode selecting page but, after a selection, the whole CustomMessageBox is closed (you cannot decide to press its left or right button).

I tried to change the code as follows, but in this case the fullMode selecting page is opened behind the messageBox and cannot be seen and no selection can be done (you can see it, in greyed, if you put many items so it has a long list of items so some of them can be displayed in background below the foreground messagebox.

```
messageBox.Dismissing += (s1, e1) =>
{
  if (reassignListPicker.ListPickerMode == ListPickerMode.Expanded)
  {
    e1.Cancel = true;
  }
  else if (reassignListPicker.ListPickerMode == ListPickerMode.Full)
  {
    e1.Cancel = true;
    messageBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    //reassignListPicker.IsEnabled = true;
    //reassignListPicker.Focus();
    //reassignListPicker.UpdateLayout();
}
            };
```

But its not working. any help??

Comment: how are you showing the messagebox?

Comment: Sorry I was not more clear. At what stage are you showing it? Can you show the code that creates/shows the messageBox?

Comment: i have used pop up menu now.

Comment: yes. will post the answer.

Comment: but you didn't `:(` I'm having the same issue here, what did you do?